# Target multiple classes with classList.toggle

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple toggle button that adds and removes a class to a `<div>`. Here's how it looks:

```js
// Menu Toggle
function toggleMe() {
    
    // Header
    var toggleOne = document.querySelector('.header');
    toggleOne.classList.toggle('toggled');
    
    // Another Class
    var toggleTwo = document.querySelector('.another-class');
    toggleTwo.classList.toggle('toggled'); 
    
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

.toggled p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMe()">Toggle Me</button>

<div class="header">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>

<div class="another-class">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>
```

The `.toggled` class is being added to `.header` and `.another-class`.

Is there a way to target multiple classes instead of writing separate variables like I have in my example? I've tried:

```
var toggle = document.querySelector('.header, .another-class');
```

Comment: Short answer is no, no one liners could do that in pure JS, unless you use a loop

Comment: Why not add a new class to each element, and then toggle that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it involves a loop. You can use `querySelectorAll` then call `.classList.toggle` on each element in the resulting list:

```
function toggleMe() {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.header, .another-class');
    for (const element of list) {
        element.classList.toggle('toggled');
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
// Menu Toggle
function toggleMe() {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.header, .another-class');
    for (const element of list) {
        element.classList.toggle('toggled');
    }
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

.toggled p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMe()">Toggle Me</button>

<div class="header">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>

<div class="another-class">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>
```

In your **specific** example, you could instead put the toggled class on a container that has both of those elements in it (`document.body` if there's nothing more targeted than that), but I'm guessing you have reasons for not wanting to do that. In any case, here's an example:

```
function toggleMe() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("toggled");
}
```

```js
// Menu Toggle
function toggleMe() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("toggled");
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

.toggled p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMe()">Toggle Me</button>

<div class="header">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>

<div class="another-class">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that allows CSS like selector and loop through them to toggle the class on the current element:

```js
// Menu Toggle
function toggleMe() {    
    // Header, Another Class
    var toggleEl = document.querySelectorAll('.header, .another-class');
    toggleEl.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('toggled'));  
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

.toggled p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMe()">Toggle Me</button>

<div class="header">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>

<div class="another-class">
  <p>.toggled class has been added!</p>
</div>
```